# Nginx Angular2 html5mode PathLocationStrategy

Tags: html, nginx, angular, navigation

Given that Angular2 is a one page site, we need to redirect all url requests to index.html with Nginx.
Here is my Nginx server block:

```
server {
    listen 8901;
    server_name my_server_ip;
    root /projects/my_site/dist;

    location /.+\..+ { # files (assuming they always have a dot)
        # use eg alias to serve some files here
    }

    location / { # url routed by client, client gives 404 for bad urls
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

This configuration globally works well. The navigation works, and I can access my pages directly by entering the url in the browser. But there are two problems:

1. When I enter a url in the browser then press enter to run (or if I simply refresh the page), it takes a very long time to load the page, near to 6 secondes. But if I remove the redirection from the Nginx server block, it takes less than one second.
   But the navigation through the application (using the links) works as expected.
2. I have a link on my page (href) which point to the root (http://my_site.com/, it's the 'home' link). If I click it, it reload all the page. That's not the correct behavior in Angular2, it should just change the route to the home. This problem only occur on my server. If I run in my local machine, all works well, that's why I think that the problem comes from my Ngninx configuration.

What is the good configuration to use Nginx with Angular2?

**EDIT:**
I have started my project with the QUICKSTART projects from angular.io.
Here is my app.routing.ts file:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/index';
import { ProfileComponent, ProfileConsultComponent, ProfileHomeComponent, CoachsComponent, AthletesComponent } from './profile/index';
import { FeedPostComponent } from './feedpost/index';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/index';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'profile/:pk', component: ProfileConsultComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: ProfileHomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'coachs', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'coachs', component: CoachsComponent },
            { path: 'athletes', component: AthletesComponent },
        ]
    },
    { path: 'post/:pk', component: FeedPostComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

And I've imported `routing` in the `@NgModule` `import` section on my app.module.ts file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have succeeded to setup correctly nginx to work as expected with Angular 2. Here is my server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_server_name;
    root /projects/angular2/myproject/dist;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the most complete setup would use `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add a redirect to the nginx but change the routing of your application server to serve the page containing your application for paths that are valid clientside.

Its nicely explained here for an express application. ( start a min 2:00)

**EDIT**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANfplcxnl78&index=2&list=PLOa5YIicjJ-VA38pChXHhq8jY2U8iYynr

for nginx it should be something like

```
    location ~ ^/([^/]+)/([^/?]+)$ {
  /index.html;
}
```

The  try_files  will check for the file speciefied in the path and will not work
You would also need to remove the first specification

Comment: On the video there is a file named lesson-server.ts. In Angular2 quickstart project, there is no server.ts file. I dont realy get the point on the video you posted. Can you write a basic example? I will update my post with the routing file.

Comment: As far as I understand, your example works with Firebase. I'm not using Firebase on my server, I'm using Nginx. That's why I think that the redirection configuration must be set in Nginx side. Am I wrong?

Comment: Ok i thought you have nginx in front of your  server but it realy serves the files. You hvae to make shure that all incoming paths (http:/myserver/ogin/index, http:/myserver/feedpost/index ) serve index.html. I am not an expert on nginx  but it should be something like in the edited answer

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I have now this error when I run `sudo nginx -t`: `ben@DevUsine:~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "/index.html" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/workout_frontend_staging:7
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`